# Error - Not Supported Exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xpath

I have a XML file, that I want to update dynamically based on the value selected from the dropdown. So here is the logic what I tried,

Reading and updating the XML:-

```
private void ReadandUpdateXML(string CMEURL)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string inputxmlPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputDataFileName"];
            doc.Load(inputxmlPath);
            var ParentNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//TestData");
            if (ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in ParentNode)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < child.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        child.ChildNodes[i].InnerText = CMEURL;
                    }
                }
                doc.Save(inputxmlPath);
            }
        }
```

I got one requirement after updating the XML value , I need to read that

Reading the XML:-

```
private static List<TestData> GetInputData(string NodeName)
        {
            string InputFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputDataFileName"];// "InputData.xml";
            Stream inputStream = File.Open(InputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);// getting exception here
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(inputStream);
            var name = from nm in xelement.Elements(NodeName).Descendants()
                       select new
                       {
                           Input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(nm.Value, @"\t|\n|\r", "").Trim(),
                           Result = (nm.Attribute("Result") == null ? string.Empty : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(nm.Attribute("Result").Value, @"\t|\n|\r", "").Trim())
                       };

            List<TestData> tdList = new List<TestData>();
            foreach (var item in name.ToList())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Input))
                {
                    TestData td = new TestData();
                    td.Input = item.Input;
                    td.Result = item.Result;
                    tdList.Add(td);
                }
            }

            return tdList;
        }

Stream inputStream = File.Open(InputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); // Getting exception here
```

**Exception :- Not Supported Exception was unhandled by user code. The given path's format is not supported.**

Reading the XML logic was working fine before.. But after updating the xml it throw's an error.
Not sure what I did wrong..
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, and include the full stack trace - at the moment we have no idea which part of the code is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Folks!, I found a solution for my question..

In web.config:-
I'm getting the file path like below

```
<add key="InputDataFileName" value="C:\Users\vishnu\Desktop\PQC project\source\Tridion.AutomationDashboard\InputData.xml" />
```

And I'm reading like this

```
string inputxmlPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputDataFileName"];
```

And in the Reading the XML code, I'm getting the base directory of that file path like this

```
string InputFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputDataFileName"];
```

So the InputFilePath got appended twice. That's why it was throwing an error.

My bad, I didn't tell anything about the web.config file.